# Qt Installer with background picture

Tags: javascript, c++, xml, qt, qt-installer

I'm elaborating the installer for my application using [Qt Installer Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/).

I would like to show a picture on the background so I set `Background` tag as indicated on https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-globalconfig.html and set `WizardStyle` to `Mac` and it looks like the following:

[image]

Here is `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>Stylesheet Example</Name>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Title>Stylesheet Example</Title>
    <Publisher>Qt-Project</Publisher>
    <StartMenuDir>Qt IFW Examples</StartMenuDir>
    <TargetDir>@HomeDir@/IfwExamples/stylesheet</TargetDir>
    <WizardStyle>Mac</WizardStyle>
    <StyleSheet>style.qss</StyleSheet>
    <!-- <TitleColor>#FFFFFF</TitleColor> -->
    <WizardShowPageList>false</WizardShowPageList>
    <Background>background1.png</Background>
</Installer>
```

How can I make that semi-transparent (white) part fully transparent?

Answer (score 1):

In your `style.qss` file add these lines below:

```
QFrame, QLabel, QToolTip {
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```